# can't get wp-pagenavi to work on a custom page on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_pagenavi and i works fantastic on the homepage but on any of the custom pages it will show it has many pages but when i click next or page two the url changes like it should but nothing else change.

Below is the wordpress page template that i am using for all the custom pages.

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Pages
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="home fix">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="fix">
      <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish');?>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> 
        
        <!-- thumbnail wrapper -->
        <div class="thumb main"> 
          
          <!-- 235150image-covers -->
          <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" height="150" width="235"/></a> 
          <!-- 235150image end --> 
          
          <!-- thumbanil title -->
          <div class="thumb-title">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
              <?php the_title() ?>
              <?php comments_number('{0}', '{1}', '{%}' );?>
              </a></h2>
          </div>
          <!-- thumbanil title end --> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <div class="post single">
        <h2>No matching results</h2>
        <div class="entry">
          <p>You seem to have found a mis-linked page or search query with no associated or related results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      
      <!-- adsense --> 
      
      <!-- adsense end --> 
      
      <!-- page navi -->
      
      <div class="pagenavi">
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi('', '', '', '', 4, false);} 
$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
      </div>
      <!-- page navi end --> 
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarwrapper">
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/left.php'); ?>
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/right.php'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/ancillary.php'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I see you have use get_header() function two time.